# Transform for loop to while loop in Scala

Tags: scala

What is the alternative in writing the following code using `while` construct?

```
val list = List(1,2,3)                            
for (v <- list) println(v)
```

Comment: This is not a `for` loop, this is a `for` comprehension. It's just syntax sugar for `list.foreach { v => println(v) }` which would be more idiomatically written as `list foreach println`. This is as clear and obvious as it gets.

Comment: Programming in Scala section 23.4 calls expressions of the form `for (x <- expr1) body` "for loops"; by nature they're side-effecting and have type Unit, as would a while loop. With a `yield` clause the book calls it a "for expression". The term "for comprehension" is listed in the glossary as another name for a for expression, but is not used elsewhere.

Comment: Ouch, you want to convert that into a while loop?  That's probably the canonical example of something that for loops are great at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible imperative traversal :

```
var current = list
while(!current.isEmpty) {
   println(current.head)
   current = current.tail
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach is bad as it need to modify the `current`?

Comment: @Howard - Well, that's what you get when you use a while loop.  While loops are inherently mutating constructs (or they're pointless except for warming your CPU).

Comment: Using an iterator does about the same think. It just encapsulates the var. The loop above works for list only, and is meant to show how iteration works on list. iterators abstract that away, which is a of course a good thing.

Answer (score 5):

```
val list = List(1,2,3)  
val iter = list.iterator
while (iter.hasNext) println(iter.next())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
var i = 0
while (i < list.length) {
  println(list(i))
  i += 1
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way because calling `length` requires a full traversal of the list and accessing element n by index requires the traversal of n elements.